# Javascript: How to retrieve the computed value of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question

My JS code computes the value of "cost" and it sets it into the input of a a form using **row.val(cost)**. When it has calculated all the costs for all the products, adding, subtracting and multiplying, I want to find the total. So, I now scan through all the cost inputs using an "each" method and create a sum total.

Problem: the calculated cost inputs are visible on the screen, however they do not appear in the source code, so, I can not grab them using the selector **$("input.cost")**

Question: How to I grab the values of the computed cost values which are visible in the input fields?

```
var runningTotal = 0; // THIS IS DECLARED AS A GLOBAL

$("input.quantity").on('change', function() {

    var row = $(this).parents(':eq(1)').find('input').filter(".cost");
    var price = row.data('price');

    if (price) {
        var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var cost = (price * quantity);

        row.val(cost);  // COST INSERTED HERE!!

                 $("input.cost").each(function(){
                     var ic = $(this).val(); // TRIED USING HTML AND TEXT METHODS.  
                     var inputCost = Number(ic);
                     runningTotal += inputCost;
                 });

             $("#total").val(runningTotal);


         }
```

**HTML**

I use Laravel Blade, but here is a snippet the rendered HTML source code. Of course there is no value visible.

```
 <div class="well form-group  ">
                            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"><label for="underlay2">Underlayments:</label></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"><select class="form-control product_id" name="product_code[4]"><option selected="selected" value="">None</option><option value="789">BP #15 Plain Felt 36&quot; | $10.00</option><option value="790">BP #30 Plain Felt 36&quot; | $10.00</option></select></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1  col-md-1"><label for="underlay2_req">Quantity:</label></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"><input class="form-control  quantity" name="quantity[4]" type="text"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1  col-md-1"><label for="cost">Cost:</label></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"><input class="form-control cost" readonly="readonly" name="cost[0]" type="text" value=""></div>
                        </div>
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: They wont be available in the source code because those values were not present when the page was loaded. If its visible on the page that means the value exists in your source code. Its similar to when we show different views via Ajax when you wont find it in source code. However, if you inspect it via developer tool you will see the values present in the source

Comment: possible to share your html?

Comment: could be the `price=row.data('price');` not returning anything. Defintely need to see sample of  html. Also note need to reset `runningTotal` each change

Comment: It would help to see some of the html that includes an input.

Comment: @Vatsal HTML has been supplied - thanks for your help!

Comment: @Roberto HTML has been supplied - thanks for your help!

Comment: row.data('price') is undefined. Hence its not going inside the if block

Comment: @Vatsal Thanks for that. row.data('price') is defined in an earlier function which for the sake of brevity I did not include. 

My key issue is how to I grab computed values which have been applied to the inputs ?  They have to be present somewhere, but to get them so I can add them all up ?  Many thanks !

Comment: @Vatsal  I added a screen shot for clarity  - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I see with your html is there is no element defined as total. So your code does not know where to print the values.

Created a fiddle for you. I hope I am not misunderstanding the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/ohus8bm5/

Sample Code below

```
var runningTotal = 0; // THIS IS DECLARED AS A GLOBAL

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input.quantity").on('change', function() {

    var row = $(this).parents(':eq(1)').find('input').filter(".cost");
    //var price = row.data('price');

     var price = 10 ;//Computed from different function
    if (price) {
       var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());

        var cost = (price * quantity);


        row.val(cost);  // COST INSERTED HERE!!

             $("input.cost").each(function(){
                 var ic = $(this).val(); // TRIED USING HTML AND TEX     METHODS.  
                 var inputCost = Number(ic);
                 runningTotal += inputCost;
             });

          $("#total").val(runningTotal);


      }
   });
  });

<div class="well form-group  ">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"><label for="underlay2">Underlayments:</label></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"><select class="form-control product_id" name="product_code[4]"><option selected="selected" value="">None</option><option value="789">BP #15 Plain Felt 36&quot; | $10.00</option><option value="790">BP #30 Plain Felt 36&quot; | $10.00</option></select></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1  col-md-1"><label for="underlay2_req">Quantity:</label></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"><input class="form-control  quantity" name="quantity[4]" type="text"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1  col-md-1"><label for="cost">Cost:</label></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                        <input class="form-control cost" readonly="readonly" name="cost[0]" type="text" value=""></div>

                        <input class="form-control cost" readonly="readonly" name="cost[0]" type="text" value="">

                        <input class="form-control cost" readonly="readonly" name="cost[0]" type="text" value="">
                    </div>

  <input type = "text" id="total" >
```

Created three inputs and the running total will take sum of all the values. Hope this will be of some help.

Happy Learning

Comment: Thank you for helping out like this. I looked at your fiddle and you have fallen into the same problem as myself.

When you enter a quantity the first time  through it works fine. However, if you go back and change that quantity the addition fails to give the correct  answer. This, I expect is because "runningTotal" is not being cleared and secondly because you are not grabbing the new values in the input fields. The result is an incorrect total.

Comment: Case 1 - I entered 6 in quantity - 60,60,60 in three boxes and sum is 180
Case 2 - I entered 3 in quantity - 30, 30, 30 in three boxes and sum is 180+90 = 270
Case 3 - I entered 5 in quantity - 50, 50, 50 in three boxes and sum is 270+150 = 420

Not sure what I am missing :(

Comment: @Vastal    Let me clarify. Suppose this were Amazon. I want a  whole bunch of different things. I decide I want:

Books | Quantity 3 | Price 10 |  line total = 30 

CD's  | | Quantity 4 | Price 10 |  line total = 40 

Grand Total = 70  

All good . 

However, I change my mind. I go back and I only want 2 books. So no my line total is 20 and my grand total is 60. 

The problem is that the line total values are computed. In order to arrive at the correct Grand Total you have to now scan and grab all the line totals and add them up again to get the correct Grand total.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a dumb question :))

It looks like you don't know which the selector to use because (I believe you've substituted "input.cost" for the actual selector you need). You can find this out by inspecting the inputs with your browser's developer tools. If you are using Chrome (I believe other browsers work similarly), you can right click the element and select "Inspect" from the popup menu -- this will show you the rendered html and give you an idea of the selector that you need to use.